# Summarizing rows on unique value, except time column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a thinking problem (not sure if there is already a solution on stack, but I have no idea how I can fix this).

I have a data frame like this:

```
ID      Visits    Time                      X    Y    Z 
1        2        2016-05-15 06:38:40       1    1    0 
1        4        2016-05-15 07:38:40       0    0    1 
1        2        2016-05-15 08:38:40       0    1    0 
2        3        2016-05-15 09:38:40       1    0    2 
3        2        2016-05-15 10:38:40       0    1    0 
3        1        2016-05-15 11:38:40       1    0    1
```

I want to make a new data frame, with:

- Unique ID's (I guess with a group_by() );
- The other columns (except Time) summed;
- Keep the first Time

So the result should be this:

```
ID      Visits    Time                      X    Y    Z 
1        8        2016-05-15 06:38:40       1    2    1 
2        3        2016-05-15 09:38:40       1    0    2 
3        3        2016-05-15 10:38:40       1    1    1
```

I tried this:

```
data %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise_at(vars(-Time), funs(sum.,na.rm = TRUE)))
```

But, there is my thinking issue: the variable Time is now out of my data, and I can't add the variable anymore (because it is not the same length anymore).

Comment: Thanks, but that is the issue: don't know where to start, because I don't know what a possible solution is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can do this with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, c(list(Time = Time[1]), lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE)), 
            ID, .SDcols = setdiff(names(data), c("ID", "Time"))]
```

---

Or with `dplyr`, after grouping by 'ID', add the 'Time' also in the grouping variables by taking the `first` of 'Time' and then do with `summarise_all`

```
data %>% 
     group_by(ID) %>% 
     group_by(Time = first(Time), add = TRUE)  %>% 
     summarise_all(sum, na.rm = TRUE)
# A tibble: 3 x 6
# Groups: ID [?]
#     ID Time                Visits     X     Y     Z
#   <int> <chr>                <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1 2016-05-15 06:38:40      8     1     2     1
#2     2 2016-05-15 09:38:40      3     1     0     2
#3     3 2016-05-15 10:38:40      3     1     1     1
```